# Adding actionbar to FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity

I am making an app that is using google maps for some specific reason. So I created an Google Maps app in Android Studio and I got an activity that extends FragmentActivity. Everything works perfectly but now I want to add the action bar at top of the screen. The problem is that the map takes the whole screen and I don't know how to fix it

Here is my code for activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    double lon = 0;
    double lat = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        /*if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            showSettingsAlert();
        }
        else{*/
        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_menu.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting mMap object from the fragment
            mMap = fm.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            boolean networkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if(networkEnabled){
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if(location!=null){
                    lon = location.getLongitude();
                    lat = location.getLatitude();
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);
                    // Showing the current location in Google Map
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    // Zoom in the Google Map
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
                }
            }
            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
        /*}*/}
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }
```

this is my layout for  the activity (Maybe there is the problem ?):

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: Post your `styles.xml` file.

Comment: Here is a great answer that clarifies this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297246/activity-appcompatactivity-fragmentactivity-and-actionbaractivity-when-to-us

Comment: Here is an answer that clarifies this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297246/activity-appcompatactivity-fragmentactivity-and-actionbaractivity-when-to-us

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Make your `MainActivity` extend `AppCompatActivity` instead.

It used to be that `ActionBarActivity` should be extended, but that has now been deprecated.

Comment: But I need to have fragment there

Answer (score 6):

I know this has been answered, but as of the time of posting this, `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated.

Instead,

Extend your `MainActivity` with `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: For future reference: You can suggest an edit to an existing answer instead of posting another one because a class has been deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

Extend AppCompatActivity actually and then use the onCreateOptionsMenu() method to set up the action bar.

Comment: For future reference: You can suggest an edit to an existing answer instead of posting another one because a class has been deprecated.