# Is it possible to use material design when extending Activity class?

Tags: android

I am building app with the sdk levels (min 19- max 22), And i want to use material design in my app. Should i extend Activity or AppcompatActivity? What is the difference? I know AppcompatActivity is support library for backward compatability, Other than that is there any main difference between both?

Comment: extending in Activity?

Answer (score 0):

Extending Activity is deprecated so you should use AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Activity is not deprecated.

Comment: Yes Activity is not deprecated. I checked it. It is not.

Comment: @DanielNugent Can u please tell me that what happen when i will use Activity in place of Appcompactivity? I have searched but did not get the solution.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Ya we can.Just add the library in the Gradle file and use it in the activity.

Comment: I have edited my question. can you please look in to it give some suggestions on it.

Comment: Read this topic to understand the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297246/activity-appcompatactivity-fragmentactivity-and-actionbaractivity-when-to-us