# Android ActionBar/Toolbar Disappears in my App

Tags: android

So I have an app. It has 3 activities at the moment... I am using intents to launch the activities from one and another

```
MainActivity > ChallongeLogin > ChallongeEvents
```

In my MainActivity and my ChallongeLogin, there is a large bar at the top of the app that lists the name of my app. However, when I eventually read the ChallongeEvents, this bar disappears... I don't remember doing anything special to make this bar disappear. Why did it go away?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testing.testingapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".ChallongeLogin" />

        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".ChallongeEvents" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your requirement you must ***extends*** **[AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)** instead of `Activity` .

```
public class ActivityName extends AppCompatActivity {
  // ...
}
```

> AppCompatActivity is from the appcompat-v7 library. Principally, this
>   offers a backport of the action bar. Since the native action bar was
>   added in API Level 11, you do not need AppCompatActivity for that.
>   However, current versions of appcompat-v7 also add a limited backport
>   of the Material Design aesthetic, in terms of the action bar and
>   various widgets. There are pros and cons of using appcompat-v7, well
>   beyond the scope of this specific Stack Overflow answer.

**Reference**

> [Activity, AppCompatActivity, FragmentActivity, and ActionBarActivity: When to Use Which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297246/activity-appcompatactivity-fragmentactivity-and-actionbaractivity-when-to-us)

Answer (score 1):

It is called `ActionBar`/`ToolBar`.

Extend the `AppCompatActivity` class instead of plain `Activity` class in that activity's java class.

Comment: Yep, that was it! Thanks!

Comment: Toolbar occasionally disappears also when using AppcompatActivity! (2019)