# Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity' , Cannot resolve symbol 'R', Could not download support-compat.aar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-gradle-plugin, appcompatactivity

I installed Android Studio 2.1.3, and successfully created a new project (just call it ProA), it runs well in AVD. That time I had just only downloaded the SDK platform android-24. I created that project with the Minimum SDK API 14. Actually , I didn't download android-14 at that time.
Then later I downloaded android-14, android-15,android-21,android-23, tried to create a new project (call it ProB), but many errors occurred there.

1. The `MainActivity`'s superclass is `AppCompatActivity` , but the error is `Cannot solve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'`.
2. There is a red line under the `@Override` tag over the `onCreate()` method, saying that `Method does not override a method from its superclass`
3. In `onCreate()` method ,the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` code snippet shows `Cannot resolve symbol 'R'`.
4. The Messages window has a error message saying
   `A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

   Could not download support-compat.aar(com.android.support:-compat:24.2.0): No cached version available for offline mode`

the overall picture is like this: [the overall error image(click to see)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYHNy.png)

the content of app\src\build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.zhangsir.aftervpn"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
}
```

the content of gradle\build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### [the screenshot of the standalone sdk manager (click to see)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNgrL.png)

---

modified at 2016 Aug,27

I have downloaded all the Android SDK Build-tools:[image: Android SDK Build-tools]

---

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Post your SDK Manager, seems you missed to download the aar files.

Comment: You shouldn't have needed to download SDKs 14 and 15, I think

Answer (score 1):

go to File >Invalidate Caches & Restart -> Invalidate & Restart

**Update**

download `Android SDK Build-tools 24.0.1`

Comment: I did as you said , when it is indexing , it looks OK, but when the indexing is over , the problems are still there.

Comment: can you share your app build.gradle in question please

Comment: I have shared the build.gradle

Comment: take a screenshot of your standalone sdk manager and share it. gradle is correct

Comment: Now the foundmental error is that when I change the dependencies in build.gradle to 24.1.0 or 24.1.1, it works well; when I change the version from 24.1.0 or 24.1.1 to version 24.2.0  and rebuild the project , the Messages Gradle Build window always shows **`Could not download support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.0): No cached version available for offline mode`** . But in the **Android\android-studio-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\a‌​ndroid\support\appco‌​mpat-v7** directory, I do have 24.2.0 there.

Comment: I have downloaded almost all the Android SDK Build-tools, except the preview version 25.2. [click to see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KB6HQ.png).Is that the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, It gets these errors, most of the time we use sync Project if it didn't hover mouse to

```
Build >Clean Project >Rebuild Project
```

If this also, didn't fixed the problem then you might have done something wrong in gradle. You can update gradle if none of these works..

And One more thing I just saw in your question API 14 is not supported by AppCompactActivity so, you must extend Activity for that. AppCompactActivity supports from API 15. For more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297246/activity-appcompatactivity-fragmentactivity-and-actionbaractivity-when-to-us)

Answer (score 0):

Try ***re-downloading the Android Support Repository*** from the Sdk manager.

Also update the Android Sdk, Platform-tools, Build Tools, Google Support Library to the Latest version.

Comment: You are right! But I didn't do that , I just modified the app\src\build.gradle file, and chang the dependencies from     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'  to compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'  , and Build->Clean Project, Build->Rebuild Project , it's OK now

Comment: that's nice. but always try to use the latest version of the appcompact library.

Comment: I did want to use the latest version of appcompact library, and the version 24.2.0 is choosed by Android Studio by default. But that always arouses error. If I change it to 24.1.0 or 24.1.1, that is OK. I checked the **Android\android-studio-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7** directory, and found I did have 24.1.0  ,  24.1.1 ,  24.2.0 there. I don't know why 24.1.0 and 24.1.1 is OK while 24.2.0 arouses error

Comment: Now the foundmental error is that when I change the version from 24.1.0 or 24.1.1 to version 24.2.0 in the build.gradle file and rebuild the project , the Messages Gradle Build window always shows **`Could not download support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.0): No cached version available for offline mode`** . But in the **Android\android-studio-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\a‌​ndroid\support\appco‌​mpat-v7** directory, I do have 24.2.0 there.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
this Messages window in this picture [click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYHNy.png)
says **Could not download support-compat.aar (com.android.support-compat:24.2.0): No cached version available for offline mode**
So I checked the first project which is OK, compare the app\src\build.gradle files in the two projects. the OK one's dependencies is like this:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
}
```

while the error one's dependencies is like this:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
}
```

So I modified the error one's dependencies, then Build->Clean Project, Build->Rebuild Project , it's OK now!

The basic reason is that my network is not available to google's server, many things cannot be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If your Android Studio showing that cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity or cannot resolve symbol R then you can do one simple thing which is SYNC GRADLE. [Click Here for the purpose of demonstration, you can watch it.](https://youtu.be/dW65f-jOCts)

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Solution Here:**

If your Android Studio showing that ***cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity*** or ***cannot resolve symbol R*** then you can do one simple thing which is SYNC GRADLE. 

"Tools" -> "Android" -> "Sync Project with Gradle Files"

[Click Here for the purpose of demonstration, you can watch it.](https://youtu.be/dW65f-jOCts)