# Android: Unable to add fragment in main activity class

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to show the current location in google maps in Android. For this, I want to add the fragment to show the view. When drop down the fragment, it gives

> This project contains Java Compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures for custom views.

**Main Activity.java**

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */


        import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

        import android.Manifest;
        import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
        import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
        import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * This demo shows how GMS Location can be used to check for changes to the users location.  The
 * "My Location" button uses GMS Location to set the blue dot representing the users location.
 * Permission for {@link android.Manifest.permission#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION} is requested at run
 * time. If the permission has not been granted, the Activity is finished with an error message.
 */
public class MyLocationDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements
        OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    /**
     * Request code for location permission request.
     *
     * @see #onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])
     */
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    /**
     * Flag indicating whether a requested permission has been denied after returning in
     * {@link #onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])}.
     */
    private boolean mPermissionDenied = false;

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;

        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        enableMyLocation();
    }

    /**
     * Enables the My Location layer if the fine location permission has been granted.
     */
    private void enableMyLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission to access the location is missing.
            PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
        } else if (mMap != null) {
            // Access to the location has been granted to the app.
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyLocation button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Return false so that we don't consume the event and the default behavior still occurs
        // (the camera animates to the user's current position).
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            return;
        }

        if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            // Enable the my location layer if the permission has been granted.
            enableMyLocation();
        } else {
            // Display the missing permission error dialog when the fragments resume.
            mPermissionDenied = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        if (mPermissionDenied) {
            // Permission was not granted, display error dialog.
            showMissingPermissionError();
            mPermissionDenied = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays a dialog with error message explaining that the location permission is missing.
     */
    private void showMissingPermissionError() {
        PermissionUtils.PermissionDeniedDialog
                .newInstance(true).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }

}
```

Is there any way of getting out?

Answer (score 0):

you just extends the Fragment in mainactivity

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [Creating a Fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#Create), make sure that you have properly set up your project to use the v4 library by following the [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html) document.

Since you seem to already used [v7 appcompat library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) please note that:

> v7 appcompat library is compatible with Android 2.1 (API level 7).

These links wherein suggested solutions, explanation and also tutorial might also help:

- [Activity, AppCompatActivity, FragmentActivity, and ActionBarActivity: When to Use Which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297246/activity-appcompatactivity-fragmentactivity-and-actionbaractivity-when-to-us)
- [Creating and Using Fragments](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments#embedding-a-fragment-in-an-activity)

Lastly, as explained in this [thread](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/trouble-with-android-studio-122), software development kit (SDK) you use for your project can also be a big factor to why such error is encountered.

Hope that helps!