# item icon doesn't appear in actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My problem is with menu item icon . I can't see any icon in action bar . There is simply just one activity in my app . In fact it's a simple hello word and i want add an icon to action bar
[image]

menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
>
<!-- black icon -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
    android:title="create order"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_black_36dp"
    >
</item>
<!-- white icon -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_setting"
    android:title="settins"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    >
</item>


</menu>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main , menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
}
```

why icon doesn't appear in action bar ?

Comment: Any chance it's a black icon on a black background?

Comment: @Ben P.it's a black icon on white background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try by changing

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

to

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

**EDIT:**

I suggest you change your Activity to AppCompatActivity and also use a Toolbar as your ActionBar

Comment: i tried that before i posting this question . there is no difference between what i'm using ifroom , always , never ..... the result is the same

Comment: @amir_70 OK, Then I suggest you change your Activity to AppCompatActivity and also use a Toolbar as your ActionBar check this 
[link](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/android-toolbar-example.html)

Comment: thank you . it's working now by changing activity to appcompatactivity . but what's the difference ? why using activity won't show the icon

Comment: @amir_70 I think its because AppCompatActivity its a evolution of activity 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31297546/3029553

Comment: ok . can you replace your answer with your second comment . i want to check it as true answer

Answer (score 1):

If you use `extends Activity` you have to use `android:showAsAction` inside menu.xml

If you want to use `app:showAsAction`, you have to extend `AppCompatActivity` as Adolfo Lozano Mendez suggested

Comment: thank you for your clear explanation . finally i understand it :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is no enough place to show icon. Try to rotate the screen (phone/emulator).