# Why is onActivityCreated() not called in second fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

I am creating an app in which  in portrait mode I have an activity that has a fragment which contains a  listview and on clicking on that listview, Second activity is called to show the data using second fragment but the problem is that when second fragment, i.e. Frag2 is called its onActivityCreated() method is not getting called. Why so?

MainActivity.xml

portrait mode

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.ankit.fragprac2.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frag1"
        android:name="com.example.ankit.fragprac2.Frag1"
      />



</LinearLayout>
```

landscape mode

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frag1"
        android:name="com.example.ankit.fragprac2.Frag1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frag2"
        android:name="com.example.ankit.fragprac2.Frag2"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Frag1.Comm {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void respond(int  i)
    {
        FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
        Frag2 fg2= (Frag2) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.frag2);

        if(fg2!=null && fg2.isVisible())
        {
            fg2.setData(i);
        }
        else

        {
            Intent in=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
       in.putExtra("position",i);
            startActivity(in);


        }
    }
}
```

Fragment1.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment1.java

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment  {

    ListView lv;

    Comm c1;




    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_frag1,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

String[] s=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.topics);

c1 = (Comm) getActivity();
        lv = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);

        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,s));

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                c1.respond(i);

            }


        });
    }




    interface Comm
    {
        void respond(int i);
    }
}
```

Fragment2.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment2.java

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment {
    TextView t;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_frag2,container,false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"OAC",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        t=getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text1);
// s1=new String[getResources().getStringArray(R.array.data).length];

//        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+s1.length,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(savedInstanceState!=null)
        {
            String s=savedInstanceState.getString("data",null);
            t.setText(s);
        }
    }

    public void setData(int i)
    { String[] s1 =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.data);
        t.setText(s1[i]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        outState.putString("data",t.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ankit.fragprac2.SecondActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frag21"
        android:name="com.example.ankit.fragprac2.Frag2"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int i;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

       Bundle b= getIntent().getExtras();
       if(b!=null)
        {
          i=  b.getInt("position",0);
        }


        FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
     Frag2 fga2= (Frag2) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.frag21);

 fga2.setData(i);


    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

In the `SecondActivity.onCreate()`, move this code:

```
FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
Frag2 fga2= (Frag2) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.frag21);

fga2.setData(i);
```

To `SecondActivit.onStart()`.

When using `fga2.setData(i)` in the `onCreate`, the Activity is not created yet; it is being created. Hence the `onActivityCreated()` method of the fragment has not been called yet.

Other notes:

- `Activity` should extent `FragmentActivity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`.
- you can use `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById` to get the fragment.
- Also see the [Activity Life Cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) and [Fragment LifeCycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle).

*Hope this helps.*

Comment: Why Activity should extent FragmentActivity instead of AppCompatActivity. AppCompatActivity itself extends FragmnetActivity then if I extend AppCompatActivity then automatically FragmentActivity is extended right.

Comment: @Ankit you are right. Some other differences also listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297246/activity-appcompatactivity-fragmentactivity-and-actionbaractivity-when-to-us