# AndroidX FragmentActivity incompatible with Dark/Night Mode Changes

Tags: android

I searched around for a while and had to "learn it the hard way":

FragmentActivity from androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity does NOT work together with the
documented way to change themes.

So for example:
You switch from day-theme to night-theme via `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()` in the `onCreate()` of you App class (a class which extends the `Application` class) because the configuration is not persistent after closing/opening the app and to make sure the configuration change (which is triggered by `setDefaultNightMode()`) is done before any activities are created. So far so good: I.E. An `AppCompatActivity` will be created using the preferred theme. BUT if you launch a `FragmentActivity` this activity will not use the resources provided for night mode.

I used

```
    void checkNightModeConfiguration() {
        int currentNightMode = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode
                & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
        switch (currentNightMode) {
            case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
                Log.i(TAG, "night mode flag NOT set");
                break;
            case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
                Log.i(TAG, "night mode flag set");
                break;
            case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED:
                Log.i(TAG, "night mode flag unknown");
                break;
        }
    }
```

to check when the activity reads out the configuration. For AppCompatActivity this already happened in the beginning of onCreate(). For FragmentActivity this happens a while later (maybe someone could clarify at which point this happens?), definitely after the layout is infalted and therefore the layout is never inflated with the night resources.

For me the easiest solution was to use AppCompatActivity instead because I do not need the backwards compatibility for nested fragments and do not support API Level < 17 ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297246/activity-appcompatactivity-fragmentactivity-and-actionbaractivity-when-to-us)).

**Hope this safes time for some of you out there.**

Sources

[DayNight — Adding a dark theme to your app](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94)

[Activity, AppCompatActivity, FragmentActivity, and ActionBarActivity: When to Use Which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297246/activity-appcompatactivity-fragmentactivity-and-actionbaractivity-when-to-us)

[Developing Themes with Style (Android Dev Summit '19)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Owkf8DhAOSo)

Comment: You always need to use `AppCompatActivity` on every API level - it fixes issues all the way up to API 29. Why are you trying to use `FragmentActivity` instead?

Comment: I took over the code from a colleague, so I don't know why `FragmentActivity` was initially used. 
I wanted to make others aware of this issue because a class which is part of AndroidX (which I assumed is a library which promises support over the most API Levels) was one of the last "blame"-candidates for me, so it took me a while. `FragmentActivity` is not deprecaded and there is no information about this bug on the web (at least I could not find some), so I thought it would be nice to support others with this info :)

Comment: You should put `break`s in your switch statement.  And trivially you're missing a semi-colon after the `currentNightMode` assignment, Admittedly the medium.com article that this code came from is also wrong, but at least it can be fixed here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FragmentActivity`, being part of the Fragment library and having no dependency on AppCompat (in fact, AppCompat depends on Fragment) is totally unaware of `AppCompatDelegate` and any night mode you set on that object.

You should always use `AppCompatActivity` if you want your activity to be aware of `AppCompatDelegate` and any of the night mode fixes that are specific to `AppCompat`.