# ProcessCameraProvider.BindToLifecycle Using Xamarin.Android Activity Instead of AppCompatActivity

Tags: android-activity, xamarin.android, android-camerax, appcompatactivity

A large percentage of examples that I find online inherit from `AppCompatActivity` rather than `Activity`. Is this really what I should be doing? I have heard that `Activity` is newer, and it is my preference. I am currently attempting to learn to use `CameraX`, and there are very few examples & support that I have been able to find for `Xamarin.Android`. After finding the following Android tutorial & a translation of it for `Xamarin.Android`:

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started

https://github.com/DottorPagliaccius/Xamarin.CameraX

However, the first parameter of `BindToLifecycle` seems to like `AppCompatActivity` but not `Activity`. Does anybody know what changes I need to make in order to be able to use `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `AppCompatActivity` is newer than `Activity`.  `AppCompatActivity` supports some of the newer platform features on older Android devices. Some of these backported features include: Using the action bar, including action items, navigation modes and more with the `setSupportActionBar`(Toolbar) API.

But don't be worry about trouble of using `AppCompatActivity`.It's similar to usage of `Activity`. You said that the first parameter of `BindToLifecycle` seems to like `AppCompatActivity` but not `Activity`. In fact, you can treat it like `Activity` to use.

```
        // Bind use cases to camera
        cameraProvider.BindToLifecycle.
        (this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture, imageAnalyzer);
```

For more details about `AppCompatActivity` and `Activity`, you can check: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297246/activity-appcompatactivity-fragmentactivity-and-actionbaractivity-when-to-us#:~:text=The%20differences%20between%20them%20are%3A%20Activity%20is%20the,Based%20on%20FragmentActivity%2C%20AppCompatActivity%20provides%20features%20to%20ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297246/activity-appcompatactivity-fragmentactivity-and-actionbaractivity-when-to-us#:%7E:text=The%20differences%20between%20them%20are%3A%20Activity%20is%20the,Based%20on%20FragmentActivity%2C%20AppCompatActivity%20provides%20features%20to%20ActionBar).

Comment: Are you suggesting that I use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`?

Comment: It depends. `CameraX` using `AndroidX` namespace, that's to say your project has to use  `AppCompatActivity` . Another example , you want `Fragement`, you can derive from `FragementActivity`.

Comment: If I cannot use `CameraX` in `Activity`, then I will probably just try to use `Camera2` directly rather than attempt to convert all my stuff to `AppCompatActivity` (there isn't anything in `Camera2` that can't be done with `Activity` is there?).

Comment: I tried to add reference about `Camera2` by NuGet, but search results show that Xamarin.AndroidX.Camera.Camera2 package by Microsoft.